# how can update column of table by subtracting two columns of other table

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

```
create  table product 
(productid varchar(10) primary key,
productname varhchar(10),
totalquantity number(10),
reorderlevel number(10),
remainingquatity number(10) );


1. produtid       productname  totalquantity  reorderlevel remainingquantity

      0001           abc               100         0                0

      0002            xyz               80         0                0

create table orders 
(orderno varchar(10),
productid(10) references  product(productid),
quantityordered number(10));
```

now my problem is i need to autoupdate the `remainingquantity` and `reorderlevel` in `product table` whenever order is placed  i.e `remainingquantity=totalquantity-quantityorded and reorderlevel=remainingquantity-quantityordered`

i tried the trigger but it is not working please help me out and if there is any other concept than triggers which can used to do this process please mention it

Comment: If this situation is in the context of a managed MRP system, then the MRP engine itself will measure the inventory level and the demand level and compare it to the reorder quantity and issue notification that reorder is needed, when the threshold is crossed.   Outside the context of an MRP system I recommend a recurring batch process vs triggers.  this allows you to employ the power of a procedural language vs just SQL.  Add a flag field to the table which is flipped when the row is processed so it wont get processed again the next time the program runs.

Comment: A trigger would do the job. What does your trigger look like?

Comment: my trigger not properly executing.... error is trigger created with compilation errors.. so please help the code for trigger

Comment: Why is the column named `remainingquatity` (missing an `n`) in the `create table` statement? If you have the same typo in your system then it would explain why you are having difficulties.

Answer (score 1):

This trigger should work

```
   create or replace trigger product_update
      BEFORE insert on orders
      for each row
    begin

        UPDATE PRODUCT
           SET remainingquantity = totalquantity - :new.quantityordered,
               reorderlevel = remainingquantity - :new.quantityordered
         WHERE PRODUCT_ID = :new.PRODUCT_ID;  

    end;​
```

Comment: it is not working and producing errors...  trigger created with compliation error.and if we insert the values into order table it is producing other error system.product_update is invalid and failed re-validation.. please help me out

Comment: @sangusainathvarma what compilation error is showing for the tigger

Comment: @sangusainathvarma this is working fine in my oracle environment

Comment: error ORA-04098: trigger 'SYSTEM.ORD1_T1' is invalid and failed re-validation after inserting the values

Comment: @sangusainathvarma run this   SHOW ERRORS TRIGGER product_update;  and check what error is coming in trigger

Comment: unknown show option "errors"
unknown show option "trigger"
unknown show option begining "product_name"   this is sql command line... i have also tried this in object browser with errors
Line  Position  Text
2 16   PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "REMAININGQUATITY": invalididentifier
2 1 PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

Comment: @sangusainathvarma u r using oracle right? try this also select * from user_errors where type = 'TRIGGER' and name = 'product_update'

Comment: yes I'm using oracle... after executing select * from user_errors where type = 'TRIGGER' and name = 'product_update'  is showing no errors selected

Comment: @sangusainathvarma can't understand why it is not giving any error..it should show the error created for the trigger product_update..

Comment: Line Position Text
2 16 PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "REMAININGQUATITY": invalid identifier
2 1 PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

these errors seen in object browser i.e oracle openned in browser

Comment: @sangusainathvarma please check what is the correct name of remainingquantity column in product table and replace the same in trigger and compile the trigger..the trigger is failing because of mistake in column name

Comment: @sangusainathvarma did u checked the spelling and corrected it?

Answer (score 0):

Or you can normalize your tables (**rewrited for Oracle 11g**):

```
CREATE TABLE product(
  id NUMBER(15,0) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT pk_product PRIMARY KEY, 
  name VARCHAR2(100), 
  totalquantity NUMBER(15,0)
)/

CREATE TABLE orders(
  id NUMBER(15,0) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT pk_orders PRIMARY KEY,
  orderno VARCHAR2(100),
  quantityordered NUMBER(15,0),
  productid NUMBER(15,0) CONSTRAINT fk_orders_product_id REFERENCES product(id)
)/
```

And use join in query

```
select Q.id, Q.name, 
  Q.totalquantity - Q.orderdquantity as remainingquantity,
  Q.totalquantity - 2*Q.orderdquantity as reorderlevel
from
  (select p.id, p.name, p.totalquantity, 
     coalesce(sum(o.quantityordered) ,0) as orderdquantity
   from product p
   left join orders o on o.productid = p.id
   group by p.id, p.name, p.totalquantity) Q
```

Data for tests:

```
insert into product(id, name, totalquantity) values(1, 'apple', 100)/
insert into product(id, name, totalquantity) values(2, 'tomato', 100)/
insert into product(id, name, totalquantity) values(3, 'carrot', 100)/

insert into orders(id, orderno, quantityordered, productid) values(1, '№1', 10, 1)/
insert into orders(id, orderno, quantityordered, productid) values(2, '№2', 3, 1)/
insert into orders(id, orderno, quantityordered, productid) values(3, '№3', 23, 2)/
```

Results:

```
id  name    remainingquantity   reorderlevel
1   apple   87                  74
2   tomato  77                  54
3   carrot  100                 100
```

[Proof SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/214e8/8/0)

Comment: thanks a lot but some more help its giving error while executing join query and the error is not a group by expression

Comment: @sangusainathvarma Ok. I rewrote query for Oracle. It`s little bit complex